# c# EWS Exchange Service does not find all items

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am currently making a small application to process a shared mailbox.

So far so good, I can get emails and work with them, everything works fine.

But there is one big issue, at the beginning of the application I am listing all emails located in the inbox of the shared mailbox. while there are over 1000 emails within the mailbox, my application does only find part of them. I have not applied any filters.

this is my code:

```cs
public static List<Item> OpenInbox()
{
    int offset = 0;
    int pagesize = 50;
    FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "informatik@XXX");
    ItemView itemView = new ItemView(pagesize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
    List<Item> emails = new List<Item>();
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        findResults = service.FindItems(SharedMailbox, itemView);
        emails.AddRange(findResults);

        more = findResults.MoreAvailable;
        if (more)
        {
            itemView.Offset += pagesize;
        }
    }

    return emails;
}
```

previously I had much, much simpler code (max 1000 items) but the result was the same:

```
public static List<Item> OpenInbox()
{
    FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "informatik@XXX");
    ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(SharedMailbox, itemView);

    return findResults;
}
```

the Program can find (some) mails:
[image]

Once the emails are processed and moved to another folder, it will not find them anymore.
EG: found 100 mails, processed 50 -> will find 50 mails to process next run.

So the issue does not appear to be a page size issue, I can find 500 mails and process 500. Afterward my program finds 0 mails in the inbox, eventhough there are still 2300 mails left in.

The way of defining when an email is processed is the following:
the program is a sorting algorythm. So when sorting the mails, it moves them out of the inbox, thus not beeing found within the inbox anymore.

However, the Inbox does not contain 242 Mails but > 1000
[image]

Any Idea on why some mails are not reported?

---

EDIT:
This is how I set up the connection towards our exchange:

```
public static void StartExchangeService()
{
    int counter = 0;
Start:;
    // log in to exchange
    string password = "XXX";
    string mail = "julian.bechtold@XXX.ch";
    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(mail, password);
    try
    {
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(mail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    }
    catch (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException)
    {
        if (counter > 3) throw;
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            counter++;
            goto Start;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the mail box use more than one pst file?  The c# is only looking at one pst.

Comment: as far as I know, the c# does not look at any .pst file rather than communicating with the Server? however, I only have one pst file on the computer and all emails which i want to look up are in the same folder: <Inbox>.

Comment: If you are looking at the Interop it interfaces with the pst file.  The pst file get updated when you open outlook.  Make sure you update the inbox which will download from outlook server all the latest emails.  It is possible you are making a bad assumption that your code is directly connecting to the server when you are actually opening a pst file.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/05/31/outlook-accounts-stores-folders-items/

Comment: If that's the case, I am wondering even more why I can see the Mails in outlook but not my application and why the ExchangeService might only page 1000 Items if its accessing local anyways. Microsoft Documentation states that the Paging is a limit for not requesting too much information from the server. I also do not refer to any outlook file as done in your linked thread

Comment: Are you looking at outlook and running application from same machine?  Are you using a web connection to the server in your application or using the Interop?  I suspect you are looking at different folders and that is why you see different numbers of emails.  When you see all the emails what is the folder name?